# Linux Mint 13 Mate: default to current username synaptic authentication

Tags: linux-mint, gui

I have Linux Mint 13 Mate. There are 2 admin user accounts on my computer. Some programs like Synaptic and the Software manager ask me to select a user name before I type in the password [image].

I would like these programs to default to the current username. By the way, some other programs like the Update manager and Samba Configuration directly ask me for the current user's password.